# Round to the nearest number in an interval centered around 100

Tags: c#, .net, rounding, discrete-mathematics, discretization

I want to round a number (up or down) in an inputted interval centered around 100 (not exactly on the multiples of the internal length). Here are some examples:

Ex 1: Length=3, Center=100, Input=99.76, Round Down=True => The discrete interval is [..., 97, 100, 103,...] and the Output=97.

Ex 2: Length=4, Center=100, Input=95.5, Round Down=False => The discrete interval is [..., 96, 100, 104,...] and the Output=96

Ex 3: Length=6, Center=100, Input=101.1, Round Down=False => The discrete interval is [..., 94, 100, 106,...] and the Output=106

I have an idea of generating the interval and then rolling though using a loop and finding the first value.

How would I do this in C#?

What I've tried:

```
Result = Length* (int) Math.Ceiling(Input / Length)
```

The issue is that this looks at the multiples of the length, but it doesn't center it at 100.

I think I need something like this, but it needs to handle all cases of numbers:

```
Result = Center + Length* (int) Math.Ceiling(Math.Abs(Center -Input) / Length)
```

That seems to work for numbers greater than Center, but fails in other cases.

---

EDIT: I think this works in all cases:

```
Result = Center + Length* (int) Math.Ceiling((Input - Center) / Length)
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Cid How would I do in C#?

Comment: Edit your question to show how you might start, and where you get a problem.

Comment: @simonatrcl ok done!

Comment: Your "solution" gives different results than in your example - see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g7TEPg - outputs `103, 108, 106` instead of `97, 96, 106` - I used the following code which prints your desired result https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sm8OQQ - but I am not quite sure I fully understand your requirements so I didnt write my code as an answer - hope it helps

Comment: @RandRandom Works for me in my debugger. I can't access that page.

Comment: @RandRandom  Maybe someone has a better solution? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
int Round(int length, int center, decimal input, bool roundDown)
{
    return length * (int)(roundDown ? Math.Floor((input - (decimal)center) / length) 
                                  : Math.Ceiling((input - (decimal)center) / length))
          + center;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. It works. Except I use (double) instead of (decimal) to cast.

Comment: I hate doubles - they're inaccurate by design in some use cases. But YMMV! Cheers -

Answer (score 0):

Ex 1: `100+3 * (int)Math.Floor((double)(99.76-100)/3) = 97`

Ex 2: `100+4 * (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(95.5-100)/4) = 96`

Ex 3: `100+6 * (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(101-100)/6)`